# How to Initialize values of template class vector C++?

Tags: c++, class, templates, vector

I learn now about template functions from book about C++. The task is to write a function that deletes element of vector by given index. First of all I make a pointer to vector's memory - `T *array`, in the private section. Second, in the method `MyVectorDelete()` I use the "ordinary" algorithm for deleting element of array. It don't gives me error when compile, but when I run the program, gives an error message, which is "program stopped working". I understand that I give only the size of vector - 6, but I don't give value of each element, and may be that's the point. How to initialize each element of the object `vector(6)?`

tobi 303 - isn't `T *array;` a pointer for array's memory?

```
  template <class T>
    class MyVector {
        typedef T *iterator;
    public:
        MyVector() { init(0); }
        MyVector(unsigned n) { init(n); }
        MyVector(MyVector<T> const &other) { construct(other); }
        ~MyVector() { delete[] start; }
        MyVector<T>const &operator=(MyVector<T> const &other) {
            if (this != &other) {
                delete[]start;
                construct(other);
            }
            return (*this);
        }
        T &operator[](unsigned index) throw(char const *) {
            if (index >= (end - start)) throw "MyVector array index out  of bounds";
            return (start[index]);
        }
        MyVector<T> &sort(){
            sort_data(start, end);
            return (*this);
        }
        void MyVectorDelete( int pos) {
            int a = size();
            if (start == end) {
                delete start;
            }
            else
                for (int i = pos; i < a - 1; i++){
                    //cout << "array[" << i << "] = " << *(array +i) << endl;
                    array[i] = array[i + 1];
                }
            a--;
        }
        void AddToEnd(T const &value) {
            if (!start) {
                init(1);
                cur = start;
            }
            else {
                MyVector<T>enlarged((end - start) + 1);
                copy(start, finish, enlarged.start);
                delete[] start;
                cur = enlarged.start + (end - start);
                start = enlarged.start;
                end = enlarged.AddToEnd;
                enlarged.start = NULL;
            }
            *cur++ = value;
        }
        iterator begin_vector() { 
        cout << "start = " << start << endl;
        return (start);
        }
        iterator end_vector() {
            cout << "end = " << end << endl;
            return (end - 1);
        }
        unsigned size() { 
            //cout << "size = " << end - start << endl;
            return (end - start); 
        }
    private:
        T *array;
        void init(unsigned n) {
            if (n) {
                start = new T[n];

                if (start != NULL) {
                    cur = start;
                    end = start + n;
                }
            }
            else {
                start = cur = end = NULL;
            }
        }
        void construct(MyVector<T> const &other) {
            init(other.end_vector - other.start);
            copy(other.start, other.end_vector, start);
        }
        T *start, *cur, *end;
    };
    void main() {
        MyVector<int>  vector(6);

        vector.MyVectorDelete(4);
    }
```

Comment: where is the definition of `init()` ?

Comment: ups.. found it ;) there is quite a lot of irrelevant code. It would help if you reduce it to a MCVE

Comment: you never allocate memory for the `array`, at least i didnt find it...

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but there's no need to check if `new[]` failed or succeeded, if it fails it will throw an exception.

Comment: you shouldnt post comments in your question (is it possible that you have too low rep to comment??). " isn't T *array; a pointer for array's memory?" ... well yes, it is a pointer, but just because you know the address of a house, you dont have the house yet.